# Firebase subdirectory wordpress redirect

Tags: angular, wordpress, typescript, firebase-hosting

I want my wordpress blog under a subdirectory of a Firebase hosting Angular app. domain.com/blog I want to be a wordpress app. I don't want a subdomain as this will not be good for SEO.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot host a WordPress instance on Firebase as it requires PHP, which Firebase does not support. You could configure a redirect of the `/blog` route to the blog domain inside your `firebase.json`. Alternatively, you can look into building a separate front-end application and merely use WordPress as a content management system over a restful API.